# make elements inside same parent div have width of their content

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with 2 `h1` tags, and when I give them background color they are the same width because of their parent, but I want them to stretch only as far as their content is, not the parent.

I am open to a jQuery solution as well.

```
<div class="text">
    <h1>Zug um zug die weld</h1>
    <h1>Entdecken</h1>
</div>

div.text > h1 {
  background: #447B3A;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `float:left` and `clear:both` if you want to align below the other

```
div.text > h1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #447B3A;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Nice one, I tried floating them but did not think to clear them. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

Since `<h1>` elements are block elevel they'll take up the full width of their parent by default. You can get around this by either making them inline, or inline-block level instead, or wrap the text within them with spans like:

```
<div class="text">
     <h1><span>Zug um zug die weld</span></h1>
     <h1><span>Entdecken</span></h1>
</div>
div.text > h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.text >h1 >span {
    background: #447B3A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7qvkL/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job for you:

```
div.text > h1 {
    background: #447B3A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but then they align next to each other, instead on one below the other!

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h9gE/)

```
div.text > h1 {
    background: #447B3A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.text > h1 {
  background: #447B3A;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* add two more point */
  clear:both;
  float: left;
}
```